# Overflowing the text of a bootstrap progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped first-bar" style="width:10%;">I want this text to overflow into the div to the right</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success second-bar" style="width:90%;">I want this text to overflow into the div to the left</div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped first-bar" style="width:90%;">I want this text to overflow into the div to the right</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success second-bar" style="width:10%;">I want this text to overflow into the div to the left</div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.first-bar {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.second-bar {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

I want to overflow the text of all the div elements in each `progress`-classed div. [You can see in my Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7r6degvc/) what I am trying to do and that my CSS works for overflowing the text of the left div into the right div, but not the other way around (text of the right div into the left div). How can I make it work the other way around? I have tried adding `position: relative;` on the CSS for `second-bar` but this does not work for me because then it breaks the first scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work.  What you're basically wanting to do is break the document model up into labels and containers.  I would restructure this so that your labels are positioned over your progress bar divs in their own containers not constrained by the same.

Comment: @JECarterII I am trying to avoid that, but I get what you mean. Actually I've had a bit of luck doing it this way by wrapping the content inside of div tags: https://jsfiddle.net/ohob3jd5/ But there must be a better way, I do hope. Thanks for the suggestion, it is a valid one indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `position: relative;` to the style of the second-bar with 10% width allowed the text to stay above the first progress bar. [JS Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/zh18c0sy/1/) I could not add this to the actual `second-bar` css class, because the first bar would not overflow into the second bar.